# Ionic: Create a $scope or $rootScope variable for index.html

Tags: ionic-framework

In ionic  app
I have a index.html (shell page) outside the template folder.

I need to access a variable ,( even if it is a $rootScope variable I am okay ) on this index.html to change the NavBar title background-color based of a toggle button on the side menu (dev/prod)

How do I create such variable.

Comment: you can try`app.controller('yourcontroller', function($rootScope, $scope`) to main controller.if you want to pass only one value just try` broadcast`

Answer (score 0):

Just like you use $scope variables in your HTML,pass $rootscope as a dependency in your controller to access it

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <p>{{var1}}</p>
    <p>{{var2}}</p>
   </div>
```

Controller Code:

```
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope,$rootScope){
             $scope.var1="check1";
             $rootScope.var2="check2"; });
```

Comment: The index.html is outside of the template folder, though I am able to pass the variable as $rootScope..., unfortunately the style background is not reflected on the page, may be because the shell page(index.html) already loaded . The change is not propagated I guess to reflect the color change. If I hard code the value I could see the background .